# Trying to convert float number to hex

Tags: c++

I'm have a function on the code below. I couldn't convert the counter to hex. I'm new on qt and c++ so couldn't find any solution from the net.

```
int outputWidth=12;
int Unit=100000000;
int desiredFreq=ui->doubleSpinBox->value();

float Period;
Period = (float) 1 / desiredFreq ;
Period = Period * Unit ;
counter = (Period/2)/2*outputWidth;
```

Comment: Due to the fact that floats are stored in memory according to IEEE 754(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format), I am not sure what exactly do you want to achieve. Do you need to get the raw bytes that is in memory? I think that you will get the help faster if you share the example of an output you would like to get for a particular `desiredFreq`.

Comment: my `desiredfreq` depends on spinbox. When it is 100 output is 35714.3

Comment: You are not really answering @luantkow. Why do you want a hex display ?

Comment: @LeoWl when desiredFreq equals 100, the counter will be equal to 3000000.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think you are using the rght approach to solve the problem...

consider this:

lets say

int a = 3;
you can "print that using 32 bits as

bin "0000 0000 0000 0011"
hex "00 03"

but what are you expecting if we define b as

```
float b = 3.14f;
```

how would B **look like** in binary representation? or hex represantation

bin ???
hex ???

the answer is:

```
bin: "01000000 01001000 11110101 11000011"
hex: "4048F5C3"
```

this is because a float number is stored in memory using 32 bits and the meaning of the bits is defined as:

[image]